# InteliJ Mac Catalina: Java 11 or newer is required to run the IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Hello yesterday I updated my *IntelliJ* ide to the latest version (2020.3.2). The problem is that it's not starting anymore. When I try to open it, I get this error message:

[image]

I have two JDKs, 8 and 12

[image]

It seems like *InteliJ* does some kind of lookup by alphabetical order because when I rename my jdk 8 to other name that goes after the "jdk-12..." it actually works

[image]

The problem is that have to rename the folders and then return the original names to make my projects work, is there a way to avoid this renaming? Thanks a lot

Comment: Eclipse also comes with installation which internally installs jre for 11. You can use that one.

Comment: Apparently you override the default which is for IntelliJ to run itself using its own built-in JVM. I suggest you revert to that default behavior. You can still run your own project code using an external JVM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This IntelliJ IDEA version requires Java 11 to run.

You override default bundled JetBrains Runtime with Java 8.

The solution is to remove this override. It's either idea.jdk file in the configuration directory or an environment variable as described in [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879):

```
~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3/idea.jdk
```

Note that JDK used to run IntelliJ IDEA itself is not related to the JDK that you are using to build and run your own projects. These two can be different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't have such file or directory in my computer. I do have the Library/Aplication Support but after that there is no JetBrains folder. Maybe this can help other people anyways.

Comment: @KevinOswaldo See also https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519. Note that `~` in the path stands for the user's home directory, so you are likely looking in the wrong location, please double check it: `/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3/idea.jdk`

Comment: You are correct, my bad I was in the wrong path

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into this issue with my PyCharm. In that case, `pycharm.jdk` was the one we need to remove.

```
~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.3$ mv pycharm.jdk /tmp
```

Hope it helps someone came here by google.